# Apache Reverse proxy is throwing 404 error

Tags: apache

I am using apache2 for my reverse proxy but it keeps on throwing 404 for my setup

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:7201/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:7201/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Please do lemme know if there is something I can fix it in my setup. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please change the port.
go to apache server.
config
httpd.conf
find and replace
80 and 8080 or 90 enter code here's you want

Comment: I have multiple sites running in same server so I assume I cant change the port .httpd.conf